# Reactjs Routing and useParams Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, fetch-api

I am fetching data from API and storing the array in 'products' variable and referring to placeholder parameters in request URL when trying to navigate to my page using route, but when I try to navigate to a page like 'http://localhost:3000/shoes/4' should return the Page with Page Not Found text, rather than Detail page. Please clarify why this is not happening.
**Json server is in port 3001**

**UseFetch.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const baseUrl = "http://localhost:3001/";

export default function useFetch(url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${baseUrl}${url}`)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, [url]);

  return { data, error, loading };
}
```

**products array**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "category": "shoes",
  "image": "shoe1.jpg",
  "name": "Hiker",
  "price": 94.95,
  "skus": [
    { "sku": "17", "size": 7 },
    { "sku": "18", "size": 8 }
  ],
  "description": "This rugged boot will get you up the mountain safely."
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "category": "shoes",
  "image": "shoe2.jpg",
  "name": "Climber",
  "price": 78.99,
  "skus": [
    { "sku": "28", "size": 8 },
    { "sku": "29", "size": 9 }
  ],
  "description": "Sure-footed traction in slippery conditions."
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "category": "shoes",
  "image": "shoe3.jpg",
  "name": "Explorer",
  "price": 145.95,
  "skus": [
    { "sku": "37", "size": 7 },
    { "sku": "38", "size": 8 },
    { "sku": "39", "size": 9 }
  ],
  "description": "Look stylish while stomping in the mud."
},
{
  "id": 4,
  "category": "headphone",
  "image": "headphone3.jpg",
  "name": "headphone red",
  "price": 100,
  "description": "Red colored headphone"
},
{
  "id": 5,
  "category": "headphone",
  "image": "headphone2.jpg",
  "name": "headphone blue",
  "price": 90,
  "description": "Blue colored headphone"
},
{
  "id": 6,
  "category": "headphone",
  "image": "headphone1.jpg",
  "name": "headphone black",
  "price": 80,
  "description": "Black colored headphone"
}
```

**Fetching data to product array**

```
const { category, id } = useParams();
const { data: products, error, loading } = useFetch(
    `products?category=${category}&id=${id}`
);
```

**Directing to Page Not Found if product array is empty**

```
if (products.length === 0) {
    return <PageNotFound />;
}
```

**Directing to Detail Page with Routing**

```
<Route path="/:category/:id" element={<Detail />} />
```

Comment: Seems the route renders a detail page, not a page-not-found, but perhaps your disjointed snippets are making it difficult to understand your code. Can you share a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Can you also clarify what the issue is, including reproduction steps?

Comment: @DrewReese hey I have attached codesanbox link, here why product variable is returned as null, when I enter an available id like /2 in the root page url. error says 'cannot read property name of null' [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-wind-n09kr?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

You renamed the returned `data` object to `products` and I am sure you intended to destructure the nested `products` array from `data`.

```
const {
  data: { products }, // <-- destructure products instead of rename data
  error,
  loading
} = useFetch(`products/${id}`);
```

Now the `products.length` check will actually be testing an array object.

```
if (!products.length) {
  return <PageNotFound />;
}
```

The remaining issue is rendering a specific "product" or array of matching "products". This is where your code goes a little weird since you pass both a category and id to the API endpoint and the `fetch` doesn't do any response processing/filtering, it's returning the entire JSON response. I'm assuming here that the UI will process the `products` array for matching products by `category` and `id`.

```
if (!products.length) return <PageNotFound />;

const product = products.find(
  (product) => product.category === category && `${product.id}` === id
);

return (
  <div id="detail">
    <h1>{product.name}</h1>
    <p>{product.description}</p>
    <p id="price">${product.price}</p>
    <img src={`/images/${product.image}`} alt={product.category} />
  </div>
);
```

[image: Edit reactjs-routing-and-useparams-hook]

Note: If you want to do this in the `useFetch` hook and still return an array then use `Array.prototype.filter` using the same conditions and remember that any renderable content will still be in an array so you will need to map the result or shift/pop the result from the front/back of the `products` array.

An additional issue is your `useFetch` hook doesn't "reset" the `loading` state when the `url` updates and the effect is run again. Fix here is to give an initially false `loading` state, and set it true when the fetching begins.

```
export default function useFetch(url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(products);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false); // <-- default false

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true); // <-- toggle true when starting fetch
    fetch(`${baseUrl}${url}`)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, [url]);

  return { data, error, loading };
}
```

Comment: `const {
  data: { products }, // <-- destructure products instead of rename data
  error,
  loading
} = useFetch(`products/${id}`);` Here the fetching url 'localhost:3001/products/2' should return a single product like this `{
  "id": 2,
  "category": "shoes",
  "image": "shoe2.jpg",
  "name": "Climber",
  "price": 78.99,
  "skus": [
    {
      "sku": "28",
      "size": 8
    },
    {
      "sku": "29",
      "size": 9
    }
  ],
  "description": "."
}` not an array of products, sorry I can't find a way to format code block

Comment: @NawazMohamed That's ok, comments aren't really intended for code snippets. If the `fetch` does indeed return only a single item object thenI would call it `product`, and then  the "page not found" check is `if (!product) return <PageNotFound />` and you can drop the filter since you'll already have the `product` object you want to render.